# Can I access Posts of custom-fields via URL?

Tags: custom-field, permalinks

Is there a way to access all posts where the value of a given custom field is concurrent? like you can access all posts of a category like this:

```
http://yoursite/category/<category-name>
```

so I would like to have a form like

```
http://yoursite/custom-field/<filed-name>/<field-value>
```

Comment: This is way too broad this way, please do some research, Rewrite API, endpoints and such, and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking if there is *native* way then the answer is no. While simpler and older representation of meta queries using `meta_key` and `meta_value` would technically fit into URL, they are not registered as public query variables.

Even *considering* registering them as such would be too dangerous in a blanket way, because that might cause all sorts of private information become accessible.

However, if you are asking if this is *doable*, then answer is that it's completely is. You would need to create custom rewrite rule to respond at such URL and limit the processing to specific (and publicly safe) custom fields.

Comment: can you provide a link with some tutorial for that?

Comment: @helle [Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API) documentation in Codex would be a start.